# Pushing angular artifacts to PCF

Tags: angular, npm, cloud-foundry

We have built(`npm build`) angular project and generate the artifacts in `${WORKSPACE}/dist` folder.

So, `${WORKSPACE}/dist` has multiple files/folders like `.js`. `.map`, `assets/`, `.ico`

---

```
$ cd ${WORKSPACE}
$ cf push -f manifest.yml
```

where below is the `manifest.yml` file:

```
---
applications:
- name: xyz-app-frontend
  memory: 64M
  disk_quota: 64M
  instances: 1
  random-route: true
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack.git#v1.0.1
```

---

Is `path` entry in `manifest.yml` file? to mention the artifacts that need to be pushed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is path entry in manifest.yml file? to mention the artifacts that need to be pushed

`path` in your manifest.yml or `cf push -p some/path` tell the cf cli the root location of files for your project (i.e. what it should upload).

By default, path is the current working directory. If you want to push files from some other location, set path to be the new root of what should be uploaded.

For example, if you want to push what's in your `dist/` folder you could set path to `dist/`, and it would upload everything in that folder.

If you want to ignore things, add a `.cfignore` file (same syntax as `.gitignore`) into the directory you set with `path`.

Comment: I gave plugin time out as `3000`, I mean, PCF push plugin in jenkins. but still I see staging error in PCF. `Application xyz-app-frontend failed during staging`

Comment: Can you also comments on this, related query, for pushing angular app? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54847855/3317808