# Staging in Cloud Foundry - .cfignore

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloud-foundry

We have `.cfignore` file mentioning the files that should not be staged in Cloud Foundry.

Through CF CLI tool, `cf push` is considering to ignore file mentioned in `.cfignore` before  pushing files to Cloud Foundry.

But Jenkins configured using  *push to cloud foundry* plugin does not consider ignoring the files mentioned in `.cfignore`

With this, Cloud Foundry some undesirable files at staging time, which makes staging failed.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: If there's a bug in some third party Jenkins plugin you need to report it to their tracker, SO can't help with that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I never said there is a bug

Comment: It doesn't do what `cf push` does, if they don't consider that a bug you should stop using it anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I didn't know this. Can you provide reference on this bug? I will go through it.

Comment: What do you mean *"provide reference on this bug"*? You're the one experiencing it. I don't know whether or not it's already been reported, that's research you should already have done.

Answer (score 2):

> Through CF CLI tool, cf push is considering to ignore file mentioned in .cfignore before pushing files to Cloud Foundry.

Yes, this is the standard behavior of the official cf cli.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

> But Jenkins configured using push to cloud foundry plugin does not consider ignoring the files mentioned in .cfignore

The official cf cli is only one of many clients that can interact with the Cloud Foundry API. Just because the cf cli behaves one way, does not guarantee that other clients will behave the same way. If the client you've chosen to use does not behave the way you want open a bug/feature request with the author/owner of your client, or switch and use a different client that offers the functionality you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is this the known behavior from Jenkins plugin?

Comment: This is a very specific questions regarding an eventual feature of the plugin, you really should open an issue at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/ , you will get the answer and/or eventually an improvement.